# queryset Q filter? Q get? how to get 'pk'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a chatting room. and here is my code.

```
def make_chatroom(request, user_one, user_two):
    user_one = user_models.User.objects.get_or_none(pk=user_one)
    user_two = user_models.User.objects.get_or_none(pk=user_two)
    if user_one is not None and user_two is not None:
    try:
        conversation = models.Conversation.objects.filter(
            participants=user_one
        ).filter(participants=user_two)
        print(conversation)
    except models.Conversation.DoesNotExist:
            conversation = models.Conversation.objects.create()
            conversation.participants.add(user_one, user_two)
    return redirect(reverse("conversations:detail", kwargs={"pk": conversation.pk}))
```

but

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

error occur.

user_one is exist, and user_two also exist. and print clause print

> <QuerySet [<Conversation: master, test>]>

How can I fix it?

my models.py:

```
class Conversation(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        "users.User", related_name="converstation", blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        usernames = []
        for user in self.participants.all():
            usernames.append(user.username)
        return ", ".join(usernames)

    def count_messages(self):
        return self.messages.count()

    count_messages.short_description = "메세지 수"

    def count_participants(self):
        return self.participants.count()

    count_participants.short_description = "참가자 수"


class Message(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    message = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "users.User", related_name="messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(
        "Conversation", related_name="messages", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} says: {self.message}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in that `conversation` ends up being one of two types depending on whether an error is thrown or not.

No error:

```
        conversation = models.Conversation.objects.filter(
            participants=user_one
        ).filter(participants=user_two)
```

In this case conversation is a queryset, that is all objects that match the filters you've specified.

Error:

```
conversation = models.Conversation.objects.create()
```

In this case conversation is a Conversation instance, so it will have the pk attribute.

What I think you're missing here is a call to `get` at the end of your query. As it stands the query will never throw the error `models.Conversation.DoesNotExist`

I hope that clears it up!

P.S. It's actually possible for two errors to be thrown when calling get, you can also get a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. If you are absolutely positive that will never happen you don't need to handle it but I thought I should let you know